# Using this aluminum L shape for stairs

Tags: floor, laminate

I m doing a laminate floor(first time) from the room onto staircase.

Now I m thinking about the transition from bedroom level to first stair and how much am I going to go with laminate.

I can get a laminate stairs ending that matches the laminate color but its going to take weeks before they custom make it.

What are my other options?

Is this a viable option?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would take yellow pine route a bullnose have home depot scan the flooring being used and stain it it works nice. If u don't have that capability have a guy do it for u it will take about hour to mill it then u stain and clear it.

Comment: YMMV with matching a stain color. Whenever I've done this, it usually turns into a trial and error process.